# google map is not loading completely

Tags: google-maps

google maps not working i have already done this code. but when i am using the same code in another project its not working. the lat long values are fine.

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div  id="googleMap" style="height: 354px; width:200px;"></div>
</div>
</div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBWT14OcdohKHZ1i-BmHEETzm6DUskY8Cg"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
        var lat = '<?php echo $lat?>';
        var long = '<?php echo $longi?>';
            var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
            var marker;

            function initialize()
            {
                var mapProp = {
                    center: myCenter,
                    zoom: 12,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myCenter,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
                });

                marker.setMap(map);
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        });
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you including the API with `async defer` but no callback function?

Answer (score 0):

The posted code works if I remove the `async defer` from the API include:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBWT14OcdohKHZ1i-BmHEETzm6DUskY8Cg"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(you should either remove them, or add a `&callback=initialize` to the include and remove the `addDomListener` that runs `initialize` on load)

BTW - you also have a syntax error, an extra `});`)

```js
var lat = 42;
var long = -72;
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
var marker;

function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center: myCenter,
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
  });

  marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBWT14OcdohKHZ1i-BmHEETzm6DUskY8Cg" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="googleMap" style="height: 354px; width:200px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```